# How can I use android support libraries v4 and v13 in the same project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm trying to use both v4 and v13 support libraries and the ADT is giving me the error:

```
Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list.
Because v13 includes v4, using only v13.
```

I need to use both because I have to use:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

I've tried to add the libraries as an external jar but then I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError

Can I use both libraries or can I replace some of those imports?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Hello, thanks for the fast answers

I've tried before to use the android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter but then I got another problem.

I have a main activity which implements a Navigation Drawer and uses a FrameLayout to load the Fragments. This activity has a method that displays the fragments. The method has the next code:

```
if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

If I use android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter I need to use also

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

And I got the next error when using getFragmentManager();

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```

I've read I can use getSupportFragmentManager() but I get another error:

```
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type ActivityMain
```

That's the reason I want to use both, v4 and v13 libraries

**SOLVED:**

The solution was make ActivityMain extends from FragmentActivity and use only v4 support library

Comment: why don't you use android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter  ??

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've edited my question explaining the reason I want to use both support libraries

Comment: make ActivityMain extend from [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) which has the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ActivityMain` class is extending `FragmentActivity`, then `getSupportFragmentManager()` will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, `FragmentPagerAdapter` is also present in support lib v4 (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)). So if this is the only reason you use v13 - you can easily get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've edited my question explaining the reason I want to use both support libraries